# How to add formatted String into List or Array?

Tags: arrays, list, dart, flutter

I have an incoming socket data as shown below;

**Example-1:**
       1#.#4#.#B#.#175.52#.#USD#.#Currency

**Example-2:** 
2#.#4#.#MyName#.#MySurname#.#MyCity#.#MyCountry#.#YourName#.#YourSurname#.#YourCity#.#YourCountry

**Explanation for Example-1:**
       Separator:       #.#
       Column_count:    4
       Rows_count:      1

```
                Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
Row-1:          B       175.52  USD     Currency
```

**Explanation for Example-2:**
       Separator:       #.#
       Column_count:    4
       Rows_count:      2

```
                Col1        Col2        Col3        Col4
Row-1:          MyName      MySurname   MyCity      MyCountry
Row-2:          YourName.   YourSurname YourCity    YourCountry
```

In dart (or flutter) how can I add this into List or Array? What is the best practice?
How can I iterate incoming string use split function and add some array?

**Update-1:**

I know how to use split function. My problem is that I need to add the string in table, array or map, so I can save it to device and use it later. How can achieve this? I need to use the function in Fluter.

```
main() {
  String mText = "1#.#4#.#B#.#175.52#.#USD#.#Currency";
  List<String> mData = mText.split("#.#");
  print(mData.toString());
  // The List: [1, 4, B, 175.52, USD, Currency]
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: Dart lists are arrays... And you have `split` already return the List.. so whats the issue??

Comment: I need to save as table in flutter local sqlite or use shard_preferencs. How do I do this? First example is [1][4] and second one is [2][4] array. But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this do the job:

```
List<List<String>> makeTable(String text) {
  var entries = text.split("#.#");
  if (entries.length < 2) {
    throw ArgumentError.value(text, "text", "Invalid format");
  }
  int row = int.parse(entries[0]);
  int col = int.parse(entries[1]);
  if (entries.length != 2 + row * col) {
    throw ArgumentError.value(text, "text", "Invalid format");
  }
  return List.generate(row, (i) => 
      entries.sublist(2 + i * col, 2 + (i + 1) * col));
}
```

This parses the first two entries as integers to find the expected dimensions, then creates a list-of-lists (of strings) containing the remaining entries.

Comment: @Irn can you show me how to get data from return statement?

Comment: I called it like;  List<List<String>> niyazi = makeTable(mText);

Comment: List<List<String>> returnArray = new List.generate(
      row, (i) => entries.sublist(2 + i * col, 2 + (i + 1) * col));

  return returnArray;

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to use [intl](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl) package to handle string manipulation . "This package provides internationalization and localization facilities, including message translation, plurals and genders, date/number formatting and parsing, and bidirectional text."

About your second question - I would create class Person with  name, surname, city, country String fields and then have  List to hold my data.

Comment: Sorry, but into is not an option. I need to save as table in flutter local sqlite or use shard_preferencs. So I have a format and list in my hand. But I don't know how to save as a table in flutter local sqlite or use shard_preferencs.

Comment: @NiyaziToros seeing you are not the original poster of this question, please ask a separate question if this one does not address your issues.